# Semigroups -- Underlying Set Non Empty or it can be Empty?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Many authors consider Semigroups being Non Empty sets. Others include empty sets as Semigroups. What is the rationale behind both choices ?

Comment: The right word is *rationale*

Comment: @Vladimir - Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely a matter of convenience. I can think of only one reason for letting a semigroup be empty: if $f:G\to H$ is a morhpism of semigroups and $H$ happens to be a semigroup with unit $e$, then $\operatorname{ker}f=\{x\in H | f(x)=e\}$ is naturally a semigroup --- unless it is empty (which may happen if $G$ does not have a unit). To include this case in the general framework, one might allow a semigroup to be empty.

Comment: Empty situation is easy to identify. For example we can consider intersection of subsemigroups. What could be rationale behind nonempty semigroups ? In what situation this convention helps.

Comment: Yes, this is true too.